# how to compile DUnit2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, dunit

I've just downloaded from SVN the DUnit2 code base.
Does someone has compiled it successfully?
What steps/prerequisites  I've to follow in order to compile it?
Do someone knows if an already compiled version exists?

thank you

fabio vitale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *projects* directory, find the subdirectory corresponding to your version of Delphi. In it, you should find a project-group file, either *DUnit2ProjectGroup.bpg* , *DUnit2ProjectGroup.bdsgroup* or *DUnit2Delphi*<version>*.groupproj*. Open it and compile all the projects in order.

Using DUnit2 is pretty much the same as [using DUnit](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/README.html).

Comment: [DCC Error] TestFramework.pas(1219): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'Integer'

Comment: What do you want us to do about your compile errors? Do you want us to debug them in SO comments?

Comment: I apologize David: you are right! I've posted the wrong notice, just to say that current version of DUnit2 does not compile under Delphi XE. Again my apologies.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else stumbles over this question while trying to make DUnit2 run on Delphi XE (or XE5):

## **TL;DR:**

Dunit2 (official SourceForge source, revision 101) doesn't currently (being as of this writing on 2015-06-01) build successfully on either Delphi XE or XE5.

To make it build on XE or XE5, go get the patch I posted [here](http://pastebin.com/aLmAexe8)

Apply it to the source tree. It should now compile and you should be able to open the .groupproj and build all the contained projects successfully.

The patch may be applied with and was created with TortoiseSVN (in case it matters).

## **Longer version:**

Amazingly tonight (2015-06-01) I followed the same steps as Fabio (in 2012 no less) and ran into *exactly* the same issue (E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'Integer') trying to compile DUnit2 (revision 101 trunk checked out directly from SourceForge) on XE and XE5.

I've come to the following conclusions:

1) There's multiple issues with the head revision with respect to both XE and XE5.

2) The key issue above that Fabio mentions can be fixed by replacing IntPtr with Pointer.

This doesn't actually seem to make any difference in the code as far as I can tell, and the test suites also pass fine on both XE and XE5 after this change, though caveat emptor - I've not looked too carefully either (and also subject to caveats below.)

3) Project search paths being out of date [XE]. Just needed updating/fixing.

4) Missing $DEFINES for XE5 and others, despite some other code being quite aware of XE5

5) Some enhanced TRect stuff that's not available on XE.  (The amount is relatively small and relatively trivial to inline to more basic expressions that will compile and is available on XE so was by no means show stopping.)

(Re 3,4 & 5 -- Sadly I get the impression the codebase isn't very well tested against multiple compiler/BDS targets.)

6) Some kind of Application.OnIdle/GUI testing bug (run T_TGUITestCase tests to see it) whereby the GUI automation tests would block unless you keep "feeding" the Windows Message queue by say moving your mouse or pressing the shift key to trigger Application.OnIdle events (repeatable on my Windows 8 XE5 and XE binaries).

Now speaking off the top of my head, and from vague memory from many years ago, I seem to remember having run into this before, and that it is down to a subtle change in behaviour either in Delphi or in Windows some time ago.  -- IIRC in past, it used to be the case that one would would actually still get the occasional Application.OnIdle() call in your Delphi app even when nothing else much was going on on the system, even when you set Done to True. And as I recall, this changed at some point due to either a change in Windows or Delphi (can't remember which) several years ago and one had to be a bit more circumspect about setting Done to False if you didn't want your App to go to sleep entirely. In any case, it clearly was/is an issue on my PC tonight with the current (as of this writing) DUnit code, so I had to patch around it.

I did this in arguably a rather kludgy way, e.g. by manhandling things via providing an  OnIdle handler while running GUI automation tests to signal that that the app is not in fact done (e.g. "don't block, don't go to sleep") and then reinstating any prior handler immediately after.  There is no doubt a more elegant solution to this, perhaps by posting a message to ourselves to keep the app "alive", but my first attempt or 2 at something better didn't work out and I'm not interested enough to pursue this further.  I'd be interested to hear of a better fix though.

Comment: This still doesn't compile for XE5 so I've applied the patch. Is there any reason why we can't get it updated on GitHub?

Comment: To handle the item 6, I added a TApplicationEvents in TRefGUITestRunner with the code: "Done := not FRunning and assigned(Suite) and (TotalTestsCount > 0);", now it is working here.

Answer (score 1):

I've supplied patches, but got no feedback from the DUnit2 team on SourceForge. So I forked DUnit2 with the full commit history into my Github account. I've applied many fixes there, including the compilation issues with XE & XE3+ and the scriptable self-tests that pause if no mouse action occurs. I'll continue my development of DUnit2 on my Github account [https://github.com/graemeg/dunit2].